# Replace String in Yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, replace, yield

Is it possible in Ruby to replace a string within a yield block?  For example, if somebody has

```
drop_down "Dropdown" do
    menu_item "Home", "/"
    drop_down "Inner" do
        menu_item "Inner Home", "/inner"
    end
end
```

I would like to change the `drop_down` call within the other `drop_down`'s block to calling `sub_drop_down` or at least do some special thing to make it known that it is inside another `drop_down` block.  This would mean replacing the string `drop_down` in the block with `sub_drop_down`.

The code sample above would generate

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Inner
        <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="/inner">Inner Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

But I would like the second `<li class="dropdown">` to become `<li class="dropdown-submenu">` which I could provide by changing the `drop_down` call within the other to becoming `sub_drop_down` which could cause the `class` for `li` to become `"dropdown-submenu"`.  Any ideas how I could change that call?

The current `sub_drop_down` method I have is

```
def sub_drop_down(name)
    content_tag :li, :class => "dropdown-submenu" do
        drop_down_link(name) + drop_down_list {yield}
    end
end
```

And the following code somewhat works once I have added my sub_drop_down method

```
drop_down "Dropdown" do
    menu_item "Home", "/"
    sub_drop_down "Inner" do
        menu_item "Inner Home", "/inner"
    end
end
```

But I don't want to force the user to type `sub_drop_down` instead of `drop_down`.  I would like `sub_drop_down` to be called instead of `drop_down`.

I am trying to work on adding a new feature in [this project](https://github.com/julescopeland/Rails-Bootstrap-Navbar).  The source code for the `drop_down` method is [on lines 28-32 here](https://github.com/julescopeland/Rails-Bootstrap-Navbar/blob/master/lib/rails_bootstrap_navbar/view_helpers.rb#L28-L32) but I am not sure how I can add the `content_tag` `:class` variable to being `dropdown-submenu` not just `dropdown`.  This question was my first idea on how to do it, and if it is not possible I would love for a solution using a different method.

Comment: Replace what string with what other string?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to clarify that well.  I added a sentence in the second paragraph clarifying it better.

Comment: You can replace the inner `drop_down` with whatever Ruby code you please. You could easily implement a `sub_drop_down` method, the problem you face is that whatever it returns has to be compatible with what the outer `drop_down` does and intent of the code is. I suggest you put the current and desired output (of just this code sample) into the question. Links to your whole project are only going to be followed by very dedicate helpers who have time to look through that much code.

Comment: I believe I have provided better information.  Thanks for informing me to do so.

Comment: How do you replace the inner `drop_down` with different code?  That is the core of what I am asking.